# Why the image is not responsive using AMP?

Tags: html, responsive-design, google-amp

I'm including the following script in my index.html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

After, in my body i have image tag with this strucure:

```
<amp-img
        src="//d9hhrg4mnvzow.cloudfront.net/welcome.jolyy.com/transparent.gif"                        

        srcset="//d9hhrg4mnvzow.cloudfront.net/welcome.jolyy.com/transparent.gif"
                        layout="responsive">
</amp-img>
```

but the image isn't responsive at all. Why ?

Comment: Have you tried to put img-resposive instead of responsive only?

Comment: How can i do this ?

Comment: Just change the layout part on the image tag

Comment: It's still not working